# Property expansion not properly binded with Configuration properties class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

Property expansion are not properly resolved when the property is binding using `ConfigurationProperties`. Or more specifically when the property being expanded isn't present, the binding doesn't fail and the property name is used as the value.

Let's look at the following scenario

```kotlin
// The binding class
open class MyProperties {
    lateinit var myValue: String
}

// The configuration
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.properties")
    fun myProperties(): MyProperties = MyProperties()
}
```

```yaml
## The spring properties yaml
my.properties:
    my-value: ${my.another.value}
```

When the property `my.another.value` that is being expanded is present, then the value is present in `MyProperties#myValue`; however, when the property `my.another.value` is not present then the raw string `"${my.another.value}"` is loaded into `MyProperties#myValue`.

Is there a way to force the application into attempting to expand the property (and failing to startup) instead of using the expansion expression as the value?

Comment: FTR, the OP has cross-posted this on the Spring Boot issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23039